# How to write a value to a port in DIO module AUTOSAR?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, autosar

I am working in an AUTOSAR project on a STM32 NUCLEO-F767ZI board and I have to write the value for a port in the DIO module. I know that there is a function called HAL_GPIO_WritePin(), but how can I make to write the value for an entire port?

Comment: `HAL_GPIO_WritePin` is not a standard AUTOSAR interface, especially not of Dio.
Or are you trying to implement the Dio module itself on top of the non-AUTOSAR library provided by ST? This way you will not get a AUTOSAR compliant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by writing the value for each channel in that port.

The ports usually have 16 channels so the value you want to write is a 16 bit number containing `0` and `1` (`LOW` and `HIGH`). So for each bit in that number you call the function `HAL_GPIO_WritePin()` and use the parameter `RESET` for `0` and `SET` for `1` to write the value to the corresponding channel.